# WHERE IN as Subquery in Postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, subquery

I have two table.
Table users has one column `category_ids` as array of integer `integer[]` which is storing as `{1001,1002}`

I am trying to get all categories details but it is not working.

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories 
WHERE id IN (Select category_ids from users where id=1)
```

When I run `Select category_ids from users where id=1` I am getting result as `{1001,1002}`. How to make `{1001,1002}` as `(1001,1002)` or what should I change to make work above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use =ANY():

```
SELECT  * 
FROM categories 
    JOIN users ON categories.id =any(category_ids)
WHERE   users.id = 1;
```

But why are you using an array?

Comment: DB schema is already written, can you please guide me better option instead array ? Should I make another table of `user_category` with column `id`,`user_id` and `category_id` ?

Comment: Yes, a table between users and categories would make more sense. Just a traditional many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an EXISTS condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories c
WHERE EXISTS (Select * 
              from users u
              where c.id = any(u.category_ids)
                and u.id = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is Subquery & `EXISTS` more faster then `JOIN` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should possibly be the fastest option, but you should EXPLAIN ANALYZE all the answers to make sure.

```
SELECT *
FROM categories c
WHERE id IN (SELECT unnest(category_ids) from users where id=1)

SELECT *
FROM categories c
JOIN (SELECT unnest(category_ids) AS id from users where id=1) AS foo
ON c.id=foo.id
```

The first query will remove duplicates in the array due to IN(), the second will not.

I didn't test the syntax so there could be typos. Basically unnest() is a function that expands an array to a set of rows, ie it turns an array into a table that you can then use to join to other tables, or put into an IN() clause, etc. The opposite is array_agg() which is an aggregate function that returns an array of aggregated elements. These two are quite convenient.

If the optimizer turns the =ANY() query into a seq scan with a filter, then unnest() should be much faster as it should unnest the array and use nested loop index scan on categories.

You could also try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories c
WHERE id =ANY(SELECT category_ids from users where id=1)
```

Comment: I doubt that unnesting will make this faster

Comment: It would be interesting if Niklesh posted EXPLAIN ANALYZE for all potential answers.